# Check Box "Check All" não funciona para todas as paginas usando datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, jquery-datatables

**Cenário:** Estou usando DataTables para mostrar uma lista de cidades, e cada uma delas tem um checkbox. Tenho também um "Check All" no qual, obviamente, ao ser marcado, todas as cidades deveriam ser marcadas também.
**Problema:** Quando eu marco o "Check All", apenas as cidades da primeira pagina são selecionadas. 
Para marcar os checkboxes uso o `$(selector).each()`.

```
`$('.chkCidade').each(function () {
        $(this).attr('checked', true)
 });`
```

Podem me ajudar?

Comment: Você pode simplesmente `$('.chkCidade').attr('checked', true)`. Dúvida: os checks das outras páginas estão carregadas no front? Ou a paginação é via back-end ou criada na mudança de página?

Comment: Eu mando a lista do c# para a view, e lá na view eu crio a tabela percorrendo esta lista, o probleminha mesmo ocorre pelo uso do JQuery DataTables, eu acho. Na paginação, ele mostra 10 cidades de cada vez, então quando eu marco o check all, ele seleciona apenas estes 10. Confesso que eu não entendo o funcionamento do DataTables, mas acredito que ele cria esses check na mudança de página.

Comment: Meu palpite é que os identificadores das demais páginas sejam iguais os da primeira. Voce poderia fazer a checkAll via c#..

Comment: Achei a solução [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29896599/how-can-i-select-all-checkboxes-from-all-the-pages-in-a-jquery-datatable)

Comment: Bacana! Voce pode responder sua propria questão, talvez ajude alguém que passe pela mesma coisa algum dia.

Answer (score -1):

Encontrei a resposta [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29896599/how-can-i-select-all-checkboxes-from-all-the-pages-in-a-jquery-datatable). Trata-se da manipulação das rows da table quando se usa JQuery DataTables.

Comment: Ao invés de colocar os links, poderia explicar qual era o problema e os trechos de código que usou para solucionar Ricardo.